# clarification on rvm and switching between rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

following http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html , I encounter the following commands

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.3@rails4.1 --create
gem install rails  # installs the latest rails version
rails -v # returns 4.1.6
```

however, I can also do the following, which would add rails version to 4.0.8

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.3@rails4.0 --create
gem install rails --version=4.0.8 # installs the latest rails version
rails -v # returns 4.0.8
```

What is the point of this? Somewhere in the text it's said that this method is to prevent global gem-set and instead install rails based on project-specific gemsets? What does that even mean?

And this is the instructions on how to create a new rails project

```
$ mkdir myapp
$ cd myapp
$ rvm use ruby-2.1.3@myapp --ruby-version --create
$ gem install rails
$ rails new .
```

why not just call rails new myapp? The text says it's to "create a project-specific gemset", but I have no idea what that means. Wouldn't this just install rails 4.1.6 (newest version) ? why not just install rails 4.1.6 globally in the first place then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you are a Rails developer in a company that has been doing Rails apps for the last 4 years. You have apps on Rails 2, Rails 3, Rails 4 - as new versions come out, you upgrade your toolset because, why not? Each new version is better.

However, they are not downward compatible. The Rails 2 app will not work with Rails 4.1. What if you are asked to urgently debug the Rails 2 app while hacking on Rails 4 one? Uninstall global Rails, install Rails 2, make the hack, then uninstall Rails 2 and reinstall the new one again, just so you can run the tests for your one-line bug fix?

That's where gemsets come in. You have environment per-application so that each application can be run self-sufficiently, with no versioning conflicts.

If you don't envision such scenarios of version conflict on your machine (i.e. if you can only imagine working on one project), gemsets are completely irrelevant.

**EDIT** after some confusion still in comments :) Let's go step by step, see what happens exactly.

```
$ mkdir myapp
$ cd myapp
```

You're now in an empty directory.

```
$ rvm use ruby-2.1.3@myapp --ruby-version --create
```

rvm creates a new gemset, named `ruby-2.1.3@myapp`, which will be run with Ruby 2.1.3. As a consequence, you have a new directory at `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@myapp`, where your gemset will be. You also have two new files in your previously empty `myapp` directory: `.ruby-version` (which contains a single line saying `ruby-2.1.3`) and `.ruby-version` (containing the line `myapp`). These two lines are read by `rvm` every time you enter the `myapp` directory: it sets the current Ruby and gemset for you.

```
$ gem install rails
```

Having recognised that the current gemset is now `ruby-2.1.3@myapp`, the `gem install` command will download the newest `rails` gem, as well as all its dependencies, and put them in your gemset directory (`~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@myapp/`).

```
$ get install rails --version=4.0.8
```

If you try this, it will dutifully install Rails 4.0.8, but since you have a newer version in your gemset and your application is not specifically having any requirements, the newer one will take precedence. This is normally not what you want; and anyway, there is rarely a reason to develop a project to comply with two different versions of a library (unless you're developing a library or a plugin; that's a different story).

```
$ rails new .
```

`rails` is actually executing `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@myapp/bin/rails`. If you were not in `myapp` directory, linked to the gemset, this command would have failed (if you didn't have Rails installed in the global environment), or executed globally installed Rails (if you did).

So, it's not really designed to have two versions of Rails simultaneously in the same project. But when you make another project, with another gemset (say, `ruby-2.1.3@myotherapp`), you could have a different version of Rails while you're there. The version automagically changes just based on which directory you `cd` into.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I guess I am wondering more about why I need the first part of my question ( rvm use ..... --create) when it seems like I can simply define what rails version I want when I am initializing the projects?

Comment: How do you define what Rails version you want when you're initialising the project? The Rails version is exclusively dependent on which Rails you are running - the one in the global environment will always be the same, the one in a gemset will be whatever you installed in the gemset. `rvm use ... --create` creates a gemset for the directory; any further calls to `gem install` inside that directory will install the gem into the gemset. This is why you can have two different Railses in two different directories.

Comment: Ah I think I am starting to understand it. Does that mean when I call $ rvm use ruby-2.1.3@myapp --ruby-version --create follow by $ gem install rails I am installing both rails 4.0 and 4.1 to the project myapp, and can freely switch between the two?

Comment: Added extra explanation into the answer.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the explanation! So basically the first two chunks of code in my question aren't at all necessary, since I define the rails version when I create the projects

Comment: sorry, I've been using windows/one version of rails for the past couple of months while learning! I am assuming "gem install rails" is the line responsible for installing rails? after I call "rvm use ruby-2.1.3@myapp --ruby-version --create" and "gem install rails", am I not putting that specific version of rails for use with myapp??

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes. I skipped this in the explanation. The part that is responsible for creating the `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` files is `--ruby-version` option. If you do this before you install rails (and obviously before you have your project directory), the files will be in the wrong directory (the parent of your project). If you skip the `--ruby-version` bit (as your first two snippets do), then those files won't be generated, and `rvm` won't be able to automagically change ruby and gemset when you `cd` into the project. (File names are probably different on Windows.)